# laravel command not found setting path does not work

Tags: laravel

I am have installed laravel via composer using the following procedure in my Ubuntu 17.04 running on the latest Oracle Virtualbox:

Steps:

1) `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

2) `nano .bashrc`

3) I added export `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

4) saved changes.

I even added this line to .profile logged out then back in again but I am still getting laravel command not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you found laravel binary on `~/.composer/vendor/bin`? maybe you set wrong path

Comment: I think you might get this error because you are logged in as `root`

Comment: Did you reset apache?

Comment: 1) The first suggestion isn't clear. 2) I logged in as a standard user 3) I rebooted the host PC but still the same error.

Answer (score 15):

For MAC users:

In terminal, type follow this:

```
 1. nano ~/.bash_profile
 2. export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

If you are new in terminal, please try follow this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfeG46VrmEI) video.

Comment: @sadek my pleasure :)

Comment: I don't get it. Why was this upvoted and even allowed to remain as an answer when the question clearly specified `Ubuntu 17.04` ?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with my Linux Mint. Check the composer folder path if this in `~/.config/composer` then you need to change the `$PATH` variable looks like below.
This should solve the problem:

1. `nano .bashrc [ or nano .bash_profile ]`
2. `export PATH=~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH [ Add this line and save it ]`
3. `source .bashrc`

Answer (score 10):

You can save yourself the headache: install from composer:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

`blog` is your project's name

Comment: I followed these instructions to the letter but still no joy https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick.

Comment: Oh you use laravel 4.2? what error did you see running `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 4.2.*`?

Comment: I saw the error I made, so I followed the instructions given in laravel.com/docs/5.4, but I am still getting a laravel command not found. Very frustrating!

Comment: I mean don't use laravel command. use composer to install laravel package. can you add (the full error you get to your question) after running the command i gave in my answer?

Comment: This one should be accepted .... don't know why programming has to be so hard ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit bash_profile

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Copy/paste

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Then run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can use laravel command in your Terminal

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your .bashrc
`nano ~/.bashrc`

add this line
`export PATH=$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`

save and exit
then close your terminal and reopen it
run:
`laravel`

Comment: Thanks for this one, everybody say `~/.composer...` then I didn't checked mine was `~/.config/composer...`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Laravel is not in that path. Instead try ~/.config/composer/vender/bin/. But make sure that laravel is exist in that path.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you haven't set the directory properly. I installed laravel as root so my directory was "/root/.composer/vendor/bin". Navigate to your home directory and do the following:

1. vi .profile
2. add **/root/.composer/vendor/bin** to the $PATH variable
3. save file (:wq)
4. source profile by typing: **source .profile**

-- remember, never install via root on a production server --

Comment: Don't do everything as root, and don't encourage that. Bad behavior because it breaks the user permission model.

Comment: I've modified my post to let people know not to do it as root but nowhere in my answer did I tell anyone to "do everything as root" or encourage it, but thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive this error, then there is issue with the path.You have to edit the .zshrc file and add this line

To edit the file run following command from terminal

nano ~/.zshrc

then enter this line inside that file

export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

[image]

To save press Control + X buttons.

Then press Y to save and Hit enter.

sometimes if you have duplicate paths it may bring errors

Big thanks to NILESH SHIRAGAVE https://snilesh.com/blog/solved-zsh-command-not-found-laravel/